# My partial object isn't getting passed to the inner partial correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view, and inside the view I am calling a partial:

```
<%= render 'shared/users', locals: { users: @users } %>
```

My partial looks like:

```
    /shared/_users.html.erb

 <% @users.each do |user| %>
     Outside the inner partial user works <%= user.inspect %>
    <%= render 'shared/user_detail', locals: { user: user} %>
 <% end %>
```

My user detail partial looks like:

```
/shared/_user_detail.html.erb

  This is a user: <%= @user.inspect %>
```

It currently just outputs nil for the user object.

Why isn't my user object being passed into the partial?

I tried this also:

```
  This is a user: <%= user.inspect %>
```

Comment: does it work if you change the syntax to this? <%= render 'shared/users', users: @users  %> and then in the other partial <%= render 'shared/user_detail', user: user  %>

Comment: The @users being passed into 'users' partial works fine, I am outputting the user.inspect before the inner partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the `locals: { users: @users }` from your view (where you render your first partial), `@users` will be available in all your nested views, so your code becomes:

```
<%= render 'shared/users' %>
```

In your `users` partial remove `locals`, but keep the `user` variable:

```
# /shared/_users.html.erb

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  Outside the inner partial user works <%= user.inspect %>
  <%= render 'shared/user_detail', user: user %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, use `user` variable in your `user_detail` partial:

```
# /shared/_user_detail.html.erb

This is a user: <%= user.inspect %>
```

That should work now.

Comment: now in my 1st partial I get: ```undefined local variable or method `users` ```

Comment: You are right, `@users` will be available to all partials (within your main view). I updated the code to make it work.